# How can I set up two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am absolutely new on ubuntu.I am trying to set up dual monitors. I have two monitors and USB to DVI External Dual or Multi Monitor Video Adapter (http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-DVI-External-Multi-Monitor-Video-Adapter~USB2DVIE2#dnlds) and from this website, I have also downloaded its driver in .zip format. I am using Ubuntu11.04, can anybody help me to setup dual monitors?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu, before you go too far, are you sure that 11.04 is the version you want?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use Lubuntu. arandr, a screen layout editor, lets me see every monitor and choose various configuration options for each. If it works for you, it'll be easy. If it doesn't, wiser people than me will be along shortly.

```
sudo apt-get install arandr
```

will get it for you.